# Symbol lookup error for mpi program

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I am not too clued-up on parallel computing, so pardon me if this is a naive question.

I inherited a parallelised version of a (C-coded) executable from a senior colleague. Unfortunately he didn't give me the actual C-code, so I can't recompile or fish around in there to find what is throwing this error.

My problem is that, when I run this executable (myexecutable), I get the error:

```
 myexececutable: undefined symbol: ompi_mpi_int
```

I have a feeling there is some library dependence that is not being supported, and have pointed the PATH to where the openmpi stuff lives (/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin). It hasn't helped any.

Any help on this error would be much appreciated!

Comment: You mean they sent you just the executable, not the code to compile it? I don't think that will work. Try `ldd` on the executable to see if the openMPI libraries are correctly linked in and make sure you add `/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as well.

Comment: Thanks so much, @Ed_Smith! Runing ldd was a brilliant plan...now at least I can see the missing links, as it were! Kudos and thanks for the help.

Comment: Okay! So the "ldd" gave me a wonderful list of what is provided where, and I notice that some of the libraries are libraries I loaded up myself, which now sit in a subdirectory of my home directory. They are on the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but I wonder if the issue is that the "scratch" directory on the cluster (where my code is supposed to run) can't find those libraries somehow. Maybe I should ask my systems admin?

Comment: Wait, you're not trying to run just `mpiexec` by itself are you? You use `mpiexec` from `openmpi/bin` to run an executable. The library path will be relevant when compiling a code, for example copy the code from http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/mpi_init.html to `test.cpp` and call `mpic++ test.cpp`, then run the resulting executable using `mpiexec -n 1 ./a.out`. If this works, I think you're problem is not with `mpi`, but instead will be that a compiled executable only works on the computer it was compiled on. You need the source code...

Comment: Thanks once again for awesome help, @Ed_Smith! I have edited my original question to make it less ambiguous, and I tried your great suggestion! the sample code you suggested compiled and ran on my machine. I definitely need to get hold of the original code for my executable somehow...

Comment: Hi! As an update, I have gotten hold of the C code! Whee! Now I am running into some gritty moments compiling it. Have added a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112056/missing-library-issues-in-compiling-c-code-ld-cant-find-libraries)