# Missing library issues in compiling C code: ld can't find libraries

Tags: c, ld

I am trying to compile some C code which I inherited from a colleague. I am running into some missing library issues - that is, the output of make is

```
gcc -L. -L/lib -L/lib -L/lib -L/lib64 -o gnd2fmdpara gnd2fmdpara.o      git_version.o -lfmd -lnumerics -lmisc -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lz
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libm.so when searching for -lm
```

I have put the libraries where the LAPACK and BLAS stuff resides on the PATH, and importantly the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but still hit the same error.

Can anyone suggest to me how I can help my Makefile find the missing libraries? Thank you so much!

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with your `gcc` installation.

Comment: Whew! Thanks, @Eugene_Sh. That was wonderfully fast! Any ideas what issues?

Comment: I see that your math library is claimed to be incompatible. Try reinstalling gcc , glibc and friends.

Comment: No, wait. It could be due to you are trying to link some precompiled *.o files, which probably were compiled using different settings. Take a look  [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193864/how-to-fix-skipping-incompatible-usr-lib-libc-a).

Comment: Wow! That makes sense! That is exactly what I'm doing. I'll try recompiling the .o files, on this current system, and see how it goes. Thank you so much for the awesome link.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm experiencing something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59011285/aws-ec2-ubuntu-instance-giving-ld-cannot-find-library-error-during-installatio